# Issue with BaseUrl in WebView

Tags: c#, webview, xamarin

So i'm having issues with stylesheets and images using a WebView.
Im using **Xamarin.Forms** (latest version)

Here is what i do:

- I POST to an URL and download the response html
- I add this to HtmlWebViewSource(), which i then add to a WebView
- I then set my BaseUrl to the domain

Here is some code:

```
string raw_html = getHtml();
WebView browser = new WebView();

HtmlWebViewSource html = new HtmlWebViewSource {
   Html = raw_html
};

html.BaseUrl = getBaseUrl(); // i have tried with many different urls here (to make sure the path is not the problem) however none seems to work
browser.Source = html;
```

**What is not working?**
The problem is that the webpage is loaded, however none of the stylesheets images etc. is loaded. So im stuck with HTML with no style or images. As the relative path is not working.

An example:

```
/images/image.png // in HTML
```

The browser dont know where this is pointing as the `BaseUrl` is not set, however when i set the `BaseUrl` it is still not working.

Comment: What is the problem?

Comment: Hello @Christoffer where is your css and image files? Are they remote files? If yes, do you save them to a specific folder?